# バッチファイルの仕様がまとまっているサイト(資料?)はありますか。

Tags: windows, batch-file

unix のシェルスクリプトであれば、 [posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) などを参照すれば、どのような仕様になっているかがわかります。

Windows でのバッチファイルについて、このような仕様についてまとまっているサイト・資料はありますか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

私が知っているものとして、コマンドラインリファレンスがあります。

コマンド ライン リファレンス
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc778084(v=ws.10).aspx

このページに各種解説へのリンクがあり、例えば下記のようなページへ芋づる式にたどっていけます。

コマンド シェルの概要
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc737438(v=ws.10).aspx

バッチ ファイルを使用する
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc758944(v=ws.10).aspx

バッチ パラメータを使用する
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc755880(v=ws.10).aspx

日本語版にはリンクがない項目(`Setlocal`など)もありますので、そちらは英語版で見ることになるかと思います。

Command-line reference A-Z
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb490890.aspx